# Windows Web Server 2008 R2 showing error

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have a server with Windows Web Server 2008 R2 installed and a website is hosted in the same. But when more than 4 users are accessing the website using their PC than it is showing too many users logged in, it's gets resolved only by resetting the IIS. The IIS used is 7.0. Please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the Connection Limits ?

You can see them on Web Sites Advanced Settings in IIS Manager

Normally it should displays a very high number (for example 4294967295)

you can see my settings in screen http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1366483/Share/IISSettings.jpg

Comment: Got it! By mistake it has been reduced to 4. Thank you so much.